# How to merge data with the same schema in oracle

Tags: oracle

We have two oracle server,`ola` and `olb`.

Both of them run on win server 2003,have the same oracle 11.2g installed, and have the same oracle service `orcl`.

While the `orcl` have a same user `login_by` which own a lot of tables, each of the table will have a primary key.

By now, you can see the `olb` as a clone(copy) of the `ola`.

Now the tables of `login_by` have been insert into a log of data. The data are different in `ola` and `olb`.

Now we want to import these data from `olb` to `ola`. We have export the data of user `login_by` to a `dmp` file in `olb`. But we can not import this `dmp` in `ola`, since the `ola` have the same schema(have the same user,tables), to the import will fail.

Then I wonder if there are any other ideas?

BTW, `ora` and `orb` can not access each other through the network.

---

Update(what I have done):

1 export data from `olb`:

```
exp login_by/000000@orcl file=c:\olb.dmp
```

2 import data to `ola`.

```
imp login_by/000000@orcl fromuser=login_by touser=login_by  file=c:\olb.dmp
```

This will fail beacuse of two reasons:

1 The user `login_by` in ola have the same tables.

2 For a same table named 'table1`,in`ola`it may contain a record with`id=1`, and the same table`table1`in`olb`may contain a record with the same`id=1`where the`id` is the primary key.

Comment: You can copy all your data from login_by to some new table in olb which does not exist in ola. Then import it to ola?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I recommend you switch to `expdp` and `impdp` instead of `exp` and `imp`.

I would:

1. Import the dmp file into a new schema, e.g. `clone`, on the `ola` instance. e.g. `imp clone/xxxxxx@orcl fromuser=login_by touser=clone  file=c:\olb.dmp`
2. Grant SELECT on all the `clone` tables to `login_by`.
3. As `login_by`, query the new rows from `clone` and insert them into the `login_by` tables.
4. Rinse and repeat for the other instances.

How #3 is done depends on the volume of data involved and how easy/hard it is to determine which rows don't yet exist in the target tables.

For example, you might just do a simple `INSERT INTO login_by.thetable SELECT * FROM clone.thetable WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM clone.thetable MINUS SELECT id FROM login_by.thetable);`

Or, if the ids may match, you might use a `MERGE` so that rows with the same id will be updated and new rows will be inserted.

Comment: In fact we have 14 oracle servers here while we try to copy the all the data to the first server `ola`.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a try.